# HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: streaming-video

I current have a setup using Motion to stream video from a webcam attached to a raspberry pi. Unfortunately this is quite low quality and has a poor frame rate.

I am looking into using HTTP Live Streaming, but details about this a vague at best especially when it comes to using a raspberry pi as the server.

If this is not possible what options do I have to for streaming "high quality" video?

Comment: Have a look at vlc

Comment: VLC on the Pi is really slow transcoding. You might get better resolution but at the best the Pi CPU will shoot to 100% and cause bad lagging,unless the camera supports better resolution encoding natively-but then Motion should work just as well. A better option, for use the Pi Camera module for example, is the use gstreamer from the OMX project that uses Hardware encoding. [Like I write in my book](http://raspberrypi-pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/raspberry-pi-server-essentials-my-book.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible, actually I've wrote a whole post around it, which explains step by step how to get your raspberry broadcasting live streaming content directly from its camera.

http://www.doepiccoding.com/blog/?p=212

Hope you like it.

Regards!

Comment: Your answer is not using "HTTP Live Streaming" (HLS), which was the point of the question. There are many reasons why HLS is superior to VLC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Pi Camera then try this: http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface

I tried it a while ago and it is the most amazing thing ever for streaming, the frame rate and quality are amazing and it has tons of options including motion capture, and you can set all of the settings from the web interface, which is very easy to use and very powerful at the same time.

If you are using a USB webcam then I have had the same experience as you; bad quality, framerate and setup process, and can't help you there.

Hope this helped!